# Controller check if record exists and send to update() if it does

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, html-select

My form is creating a new record but I want it to check if the user_id exists first and send to update if it does.

My form in my edit web page:

```
<%= form_for @trained, :url => certificates_path, :method => :post do |f| %>
  <p> Non-Trained Users </p>
<%= select_tag "certificate[user_id]", options_for_select(@non_trained.collect{|x| [x.name, x.id]}), {:multiple => :multiple} %>
  <%= f.submit "Train", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

My edit() in the controller, it seems to ignore my if statement and errors if it can't find the record. **How do I check for the record existing first and send to update() if it does?**

```
if @trained = Certificate.find(params[:certificate])
else
  @trained = Certificate.new(params[:certificate])
end
```

This is my resource controller that is actually doing the work.

```
class CertificatesController < ApplicationController

  def create

    @trained = Certificate.new(params[:certificate])
    if @trained.save
      @trained.update_attributes(attend: "Yes")
    end
    redirect_to grandstreamers_resellers_path

  end

  def update
    @trained = Certificate.where(user_id: params[:certificate][:user_id])
    @trained.first.update_attributes(attend: "No")
    @untrained = Certificate.where(user_id: params[:certificate][:user_id])
    @untrained.first.update_attributes(attend: "No")
    redirect_to grandstreamers_resellers_path
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally tend to find code cleaner if variable assignment is not performed as part of a conditional statement. However, if you want to avoid a second assignment after the initial find you can do it as follows.

I'd suggest changing these lines:

```
if @trained = Certificate.find(params[:certificate])
else
  @trained = Certificate.new(params[:certificate])
end
```

To something like this: (note the change in params ... you should be finding the certificate using an ID or some other attribute, not the entire params hash)

```
@trained = Certificate.find_by_id(params[:id]) || Certificate.new(params[:certificate])
```

Of course, you could also use the `find_or_create_by` method ...

Comment: It gives me an error that it cant find the record if it does not exist. That is why I put it as an if statement but it still examines the statement.

Comment: Change the find to use find_by_id ... this wont raise an exception. I'll update my example for you.